# Design neural network to find inputs with highest probability of class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am designing a neural network for classification with the aim to find the inputs with the highest probability that they belong to one of two classes.

There are two classes, class `A` and class `B`. I have a set of data of which I want to find the inputs that have the highest probability that they belong to class `B`.

This is different to conventional classification in that I'm not interested in the correct labelling of all inputs. I'm only interested in the correct labelling of the inputs that are labelled with a high probability to belong to class `B`.

So the accuracy of the network could be calculated like this:

- Train the neural network
- Feed the validation data into the network
- Sort the resulting outputs, together with the known targets, by the returned probability for class `B`
- Take the top `N` samples, e.g. top 1% (now we have the outputs with the highest probability for class `B`)
- Count how many of the taken samples were actually of class `B`
- The accuracy is the number of actual instances of class `B` counted, divided by the number of samples taken `N`

Say, we have a simple network like this:

```
        model = keras.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Dense(7,
                               input_dim=len(inputs_training[0]),
                               activation=tf.nn.relu,
                               kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.0)),
            keras.layers.Dense(7, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.000001)),
            keras.layers.Dense(7, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.000001)),
            keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.00000))
        ])
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=binary_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(
            np.array(inputs_training),
            np.array(targets_training),
            epochs=15,
            verbose=0,
            class_weight={0: 1, 1: 4}
        )
```

The problem is that, the more features (inputs) I add, the less accurate the prediction becomes - even though each features performs well on it's own. For example, I can use a single feature that gives me 40% accuracy in the top 1%. If I add two more features that perform similarly on their own, the accuracy drops to, say, 25-30%. Class `B` makes about 15% of the data.

The second problem is that the accuracy in the top 1% fluctuates a lot.

I have tried:

- Changing the number of layers / neurons, epochs
- Changing the class weights
- Changing regularisation parameters, including using `l1`
- Trying different loss functions

I speculate that none of this works because the neural network is optimising for the classification of all inputs, not optimizing to produce the highest accuracy in the top 1%.

Is there a way how I can stir the neural network to optimize so that the most probable results are correct, but the remaining 99% can tend to be mislabelled?

Demo code:
https://pastebin.com/CnDpCjdp

Comment: Have you tried giving a higher weight to class B? You are giving it a weigth of 4 but if it's 15% of the data, B's weight can go up a bit (let's say around 8)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have (see point 2 of what I tried). There's also a demo file at the end of the post - a bit messy I admit. I think what's needed is a customised loss function.

Comment: Using your code, I got 16% with 1 feature and 42% with 3. If I increase the number of nodes of the first two layers to be 100 each, I get 43% and 83%. I does varies a lot but the input data is very random. Is your real data this random?

Comment: Increasing the nodes indeed helps! Interesting! Will look into that, thanks. Your first reading is due to the mentioned fluctuations though - if you enable verbosity that becomes apparent.

Comment: Another interesting thing is that in the 1 feature version, the accuracy is quite similar to the average value of B.